# Formal proof for in-balanced pipeline throughput

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines

It is a well known fact, the throughput of a given compute pipeline (say, CPU instruction pipeline) is determined by its "slow" segment.

All the resources I've seen so far, demonstrates this fact via describing a **concrete** pipeline with 2-3 stages.

I'd love to see, more-or-less, some formal proof, the above holds for any in-balanced K-pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

This is formalized in [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), which provides a quantitative version of that claim.